# How can you convert a List<X> to Dictionary<X,Y> filling the value with null?

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary

I am trying to populate a Dictionary with a List as keys and null as values. How can i achieve this ? I am programming in C#

Thanks.

Comment: @austinwernli That appears to be asking something else

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can also use the Linq [`Enumerable.ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), specifying the key and value as null:

```
var myList = new List<string> { "first", "second" };
Dictionary<string, string> dict = myList.ToDictionary(
    item => item,         // key 
    item => (string)null  // value
);
```

Note that you need to cast "null" to your element type, otherwise C# can't infer the type of the second lambda expression.

Comment: This is what i have tried, but i get the following error : "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<X>' because it is not a delegate type "

Comment: @Negashion I noticed that after I posted -- see my edit.  You just need to cast null to a definite type.  (C# can't infer any type from a null reference.)

Comment: Ok, i just saw your edit. That damned cast has given me trouble ! =) Thanks, works like a charm.

Comment: Dictioary with default values 0
var res = myList.Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x, x => Convert.ToInt32("0"));

Answer (score 1):

Just using a loop is simple enough:

```
foreach (var item in myList)
   myDictionary.Add(item, null);
```

This assumes, of course, that you have already created the `Dictionary`.